# How to log tornado socket accept time?

Tags: python, tornado

When I read tornado source code, I want to log every `socket` accept time, so I add a log on `accept_handler` like this:

```
def accept_handler(fd, events):
    for i in xrange(_DEFAULT_BACKLOG):
        if removed[0]:
            # The socket was probably closed
            return
        try:
            connection, address = sock.accept()
        except socket.error as e:
            # _ERRNO_WOULDBLOCK indicate we have accepted every
            # connection that is available.
            if errno_from_exception(e) in _ERRNO_WOULDBLOCK:
                return
            # ECONNABORTED indicates that there was a connection
            # but it was closed while still in the accept queue.
            # (observed on FreeBSD).
            if errno_from_exception(e) == errno.ECONNABORTED:
                continue
            raise
        set_close_exec(connection.fileno())
        gen_log.warning('accept at {}'.format(io_loop.time()))
        callback(connection, address)
```

My handler is a blocking function, it blocks ioloop 3s and return 'hello world'.

Then I send 10 requests simultaneously via thread, I found tornado log is like this:

```
[W 170916 22:06:01 netutil:278] accept at 1505624761.04
sleep at 1505624761.04
wake at 1505624764.04
[I 170916 22:06:04 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3005.47ms
[W 170916 22:06:04 netutil:278] accept at 1505624764.04
sleep at 1505624764.04
wake at 1505624767.05
[I 170916 22:06:07 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3005.02ms
[W 170916 22:06:07 netutil:278] accept at 1505624767.05
sleep at 1505624767.05
wake at 1505624770.05
[I 170916 22:11:06 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3003.87ms
[W 170916 22:11:06 netutil:278] accept at 1505625066.86
sleep at 1505625066.86
wake at 1505625069.86
[I 170916 22:11:09 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3002.22ms
[W 170916 22:11:09 netutil:278] accept at 1505625069.86
sleep at 1505625069.86
wake at 1505625072.87
[I 170916 22:11:12 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3004.91ms
[W 170916 22:11:12 netutil:278] accept at 1505625072.87
sleep at 1505625072.87
wake at 1505625075.87
[I 170916 22:11:15 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3004.71ms
[W 170916 22:11:15 netutil:278] accept at 1505625075.87
sleep at 1505625075.87
wake at 1505625078.88
[I 170916 22:11:18 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3006.12ms
[W 170916 22:11:18 netutil:278] accept at 1505625078.88
sleep at 1505625078.88
wake at 1505625081.89
[I 170916 22:11:21 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3006.07ms
[W 170916 22:11:21 netutil:278] accept at 1505625081.89
sleep at 1505625081.89
wake at 1505625084.89
[I 170916 22:11:24 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3005.07ms
[W 170916 22:11:24 netutil:278] accept at 1505625084.9
sleep at 1505625084.9
wake at 1505625087.9
[I 170916 22:11:27 web:2063] 200 GET / (192.168.10.243) 3006.34ms
```

it looks like tornado process requests one by one, but I think that's not true and I use `wireshark` finding all connections are accepted in a very short time, so I don't know how to adding a log to display every `socket` accept time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tornado, a blocking handler blocks *everything*. That includes, in this case, the next call to `accept()` (the call to `callback()` at the end of the accept loop will eventually reach the handler). To have any concurrency in Tornado you must make all your handlers non-blocking (on the IOLoop thread. You can use a ThreadPoolExecutor to move work to other threads, and in those threads you can block as much as you want, but you can't call other Tornado methods).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of why I would ask this question is derived from my misunderstanding of `socket`.

When I read `tornado` source code, I thought after server called `sock.accept`, the connection turned state to `ESTABLISHED`, that's not true, even I don't start `ioloop`, clients can connect to server and these sockets can be established unless reaching default listen `backlog(128)`.